# Fraction field of DVR isomorphic to its $\mathfrak{p}$-completion

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring with fraction field $K$, maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ and discrete valuation $v = v_\mathfrak{p}$.
Assume that $A \simeq \varprojlim A/\mathfrak{p}^n$.
Is the field $K$ complete for the absolute value $\lvert x \rvert = c^{v(x)}$ (with $0 < c < 1$) ?

Comment: If $\cong$ is the natural map then yes sure. Not sure if it works without this hypothesis, doesn't seem easy.

Comment: Is my first assertion unclear to you ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The natural map makes $A$ a subring of $\varprojlim A/\mathfrak{p}^n$, the $\cong$ means they are equal.

Comment: @reuns the distinction in this case does not make any difference. $\varprojlim_n A/\mathfrak{p}^n$ is a DVR which is max-adically complete. If there is an abstract isomorphism $A \simeq \varprojlim_n A/\mathfrak{p}^n$, the same is true of $A$, hence the canonical map $A \rightarrow \varprojlim_n A/\mathfrak{p}^n$ is also an isomorphism.

Comment: @reuns For a local ring $A$, being complete for its unique maximal ideal is a property preserved by an (abstract) isomorphism of rings. The ring $\varprojlim_n A/\mathfrak{p}^n$ has this property. Hence so does $A$, given an abstract isomorphism between them.

Comment: @PavelČoupek Yes of course there is only one maximal ideal, the isomorphism sends one to the other so it is continuous. I was too much thinking to $Frac(A)$. So my first comment should be read : if $Frac(A)\cong Frac(\varprojlim A/\mathfrak{p}^n)$ but no continuity restriction on $\cong$ then it is not obvious